# Html Web site doesn't scroll on android phone but works well on IOS and Desktop

Tags: html, css, web

Hello guys I am trying to figure out how to solve this issue: I have a responsive html website that it's working well when open on a desktop browser, but when I open it on mobile it stuck and cannot scroll. Any idea what's wrong?
Thank you

Link: http://smartwork.com.bo/demo/Forrest/index.html

```
    <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Morshed">

    <title>Forrest | Mundo Digital</title>

    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta
    ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, user-scalable=yes, minimal-ui">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon2.png" />

    <!-- CSS
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Fontawesome Icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- bootstrap.min css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
    <!-- Grid Component css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
    <!-- Slit Slider css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slit-slider.css">
    <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- Media Queries -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media-queries.css">
```

**Css Code**

```
body {
    background-color: #2B2C30;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #ddd;


}
```

Comment: Can you paste the source code including stylesheet content?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue with the following code before the body.

```
html,
body {    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:visible;
}
body {
    background-color: #2B2C30;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #ddd;
    overflow: a;
}
```

Hope it helps you guys if you find the same code error.